# SQL AS/400 - Extract product price per store

Tags: sql, select, ibm-midrange

We have a phone dialer who call us store to **inform** them about gas price in their region.

We have 3 tables (WBDAPP00,WBDCIE00,WBDCIA00)

`WBDAPP00` is where we store information about the call.
`DANOID` = ID
`DA#INT`,`DA#IND`,`DA#TEL` = phone number
`DA#ENV` = The number of group call, we send 1 message to few store.
`DASTAT` = The status of the call (Confirm by store,canceled,running, confirmed by us, in pause)
`DADTHR` = The timestamp of the last status modification

`WBDCIE00` is where we store information about the group of store
`CIE#EN` = ID
`CIEDHC` = The timestamp where the call is effective, we can call the morning to tell the price will change at 14h30
`CIE$OR` = The price for regular
`CIE$PL` = The price for plus
`CIE$SP` = The price for super
`CIE$DI` = The price for diesel

`WBDCIA00` is complementary information about `WBDAPP00`
`CIA#ST` = The ID of the store
`CIA#AP` = The ID of the call
`CIE#EN` = The ID of the group call
`CIABAN` = This is the number of the compagny of the store

This is a sample output of these 3 tables

```
SELECT * FROM PRDCM/WBDAPP00 WHERE DA#ENV = 17258 OR DA#ENV = 17257
```

```
+--------+--------+--------+---------+--------+--------+----------------------------+-----------+--------+
| DANOID | DA#INT | DA#IND |  DA#TEL | DA#ENV | DASTAT |          DADTHR            |   DAPARM  | DAMUSR |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+--------+--------+----------------------------+-----------+--------+
| 100420 |      1 |    418 | 9600055 |  17257 |   4    | 2012-05-07-09.15.04.768228 |1;2;1;1;1;1| ISALAP |
| 100421 |      1 |    819 | 7346491 |  17258 |   0    | 2012-05-07-09.23.32.362971 |0;4;0;1;0;0| ISALAP |
| 100422 |      1 |    819 | 7624747 |  17258 |   1    | 2012-05-07-09.24.28.042330 |0;3;1;1;0;1| ISALAP |
| 100423 |      1 |    819 | 6377874 |  17258 |   0    | 2012-05-07-09.23.32.803073 |0;3;0;1;0;1| ISALAP |
| 100424 |      1 |    819 | 8742844 |  17258 |   1    | 2012-05-07-09.24.25.347116 |1;1;1;1;0;1| ISALAP |
| 100425 |      1 |    819 | 8255744 |  17258 |   0    | 2012-05-07-09.23.33.207688 |1;3;1;1;0;1| ISALAP |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+--------+--------+----------------------------+-----------+--------+
```

```
SELECT * FROM PRDCM/WBDCIE00 WHERE CIE#EN = 17258 OR CIE#EN = 17257
```

```
+--------+----------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CIE#EN |           CIEDHC           | CIE$OR | CIE$PL | CIE$SP | CIE$DI |
+--------+----------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  17257 | 2012-05-04-17.00.00.000000 |      0 |      0 |      0 |  1,359 |
|  17258 | 2012-05-07-09.30.00.000000 |  1,354 |      0 |      0 |      0 |
+--------+----------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

```
SELECT * FROM PRDCM/WBDCIA00 WHERE CIA#EN = 17258 OR CIA#EN = 17257
```

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CIA#ST | CIA#AP | CIA#EN | CIABAN |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     96 | 100420 |  17257 |      2 |
|    316 | 100421 |  17258 |      4 |
|    320 | 100422 |  17258 |      3 |
|    321 | 100423 |  17258 |      3 |
|    338 | 100424 |  17258 |      1 |
|    366 | 100425 |  17258 |      3 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

This is the relation between tables
`CIA#AP` = `DANOID`
`CIA#EN` = `CIE#EN` = `DA#ENV`

I want to extract the last `CIE$OR` (not 0) and the last `CIE$DI` (not 0) for each `CIA#ST`.
The last one is determined by `CIEDHC` (Desc order).
`DASTAT` needs to be 1 or 4.

This is an example of want I want to extract from the data above :

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| CIA#ST | CIE$OR | CIE$DI |
+--------+--------+--------+
|     96 |      0 |  1,359 |
|    316 |  1,354 |      0 |
|    320 |  1,354 |      0 |
|    321 |  1,354 |      0 |
|    338 |  1,354 |      0 |
|    366 |  1,354 |      0 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Or like this one, that's not ideal but I will tolerate it in this case

```
+--------+-------------+-------+
| CIA#ST | productType | price |
+--------+-------------+-------+
|     96 |           3 | 1,359 |
|    316 |           6 | 1,354 |
|    320 |           6 | 1,354 |
|    321 |           6 | 1,354 |
|    338 |           6 | 1,354 |
|    366 |           6 | 1,354 |
+--------+-------------+-------+
```

For those who don't know AS400, `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` is equal to `TOP 1` AND `LIMIT 1`

`LAST` does not exist in AS400 so I need to replace
`SELECT LAST(Column1) AS test FROM table1`
by
`SELECT Column1,Column2 FROM table1 ORDER BY Column2 DESC LIMIT 1`

I have tried with subselect but you can't use `ORDER BY` and `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`.
We are in V5R1 without any PTF.

This is an exemple of extraction

```
SELECT CIA#ST,CIE$OR,CIE$DI,CIEDHC 
FROM PRDCM/WBDAPP03 
INNER JOIN PRDCM/WBDCIE01 ON CIE#EN = DA#ENV 
INNER JOIN PRDCM/WBDCIA01 ON CIA#AP = DANOID 
WHERE DASTAT IN (1,4)
ORDER BY CIEDHC,DA#ENV
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
```

```
+--------+--------+--------+----------------------------+
| CIA#ST | CIE$OR | CIE$DI |          CIEDHC            |
+--------+--------+--------+----------------------------+
|     88 |  1,014 |  1,039 | 2010-08-25-09.00.00.000000 |
|     89 |  1,014 |  1,039 | 2010-08-25-09.00.00.000000 |
|     90 |  1,014 |  1,039 | 2010-08-25-09.00.00.000000 |
|     91 |  1,014 |  1,039 | 2010-08-25-09.00.00.000000 |
|    119 |  1,084 |      0 | 2010-08-25-09.00.00.000000 |
|    522 |  1,014 |  1,039 | 2010-08-25-09.00.00.000000 |
+--------+--------+--------+----------------------------+
```

I'll try all your suggestions.

Comment: You're going to have to fix your sample/result data, because there isn't a row where `CIE$OR = 1.587`.  You also don't appear to have any links that would allow you to connect `CIA#ST = 119` to `CIE$DI = 1.120`, given the relationships you've listed.  Anonymyzing your data is great, although I doubt it'd be possible to get anything useful out of solely these three tables (well, besides what _may_ be telephone numbers).  Could you also show what you _have_ tried so far, just so we know what doesn't work?  And please list your OS version (although I'm assuming V6R1+).

Comment: This can be solved with a clever use of subqueries and aggregate grouping.  You have two different join conditions for `WBDCIA00` and `WBDAPP00`.  Can the relationship `CIA#AP = DANOID` and `CIA#EN <> DA#ENV` exist for a single match?  It may be easier to figure out if you provide a brief description of the tables and fields.

Comment: @X-Zero -> I got permission to put real data, so i edited it. I'll add new try. I added us version of as400 too.

Comment: @JamesA No, this relationship doesn't exist. I updated my text to give you a chance to understand. I'll try sub-queries and aggregate grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, I'm a little twitchy about your schema here - there's some denormalization I'm not happy with, among other things (a multi-value column, really?).  But you probably have a limited ability to change it, so...  If possible, you should consider upgrading to at least V6R1 (which is what we're on), as the database gets more goodies.  Thankfully, you still have CTEs, which will help a bit.

I'm assuming that what you want is the latest price change for a store (given by `CIEDHC`) with a call for that store in `DASTAT` as 1 or 4, *not* given by the call-time (so, what happens if an earlier group-call is 'confirmed' after a later one?).  In other words, this isn't the last 'confirmed' change, it's the last 'entered' change.

I'm also assuming you have a 'store' table, with all the actual store ids defined.  However, since you didn't list it, I created a CTE to manufacture one.  You can (and probably should) swap it out in the resulting statement.

```
WITH Store (storeId) as (
            SELECT DISTINCT cia#st
            FROM Wbdcia00), 
     Price_Change (callGroup, occurredAt, productType, newPrice) as (
                   SELECT cie#en, ciedhc, 1, cie$or
                   FROM Wbdcie00
                   WHERE cie$or > 0
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT cie#en, ciedhc, 4, cie$di
                   FROM Wbdcie00 
                   WHERE cie$di > 0), 
     Confirmed_Changes (storeId, occurredAt, productType, newPrice) as (
                        SELECT WarehouseCall.cia#st, Change.occurredAt, 
                               Change.productType, Change.newPrice
                        FROM Wbdcia00 as WarehouseCall
                        JOIN Wbdapp00 as Call
                        ON Call.danoid = WarehouseCall.cia#ap
                        AND Call.dastat IN (1, 4)
                        JOIN Price_Change as Change
                        ON Change.callGroup = da#env),
     Latest_Change (storeId, productType, newPrice) as (
                    SELECT Actual.storeId, Actual.productType, Actual.newPrice
                    FROM Confirmed_Changes as Actual
                    EXCEPTION JOIN Confirmed_Changes as Remove
                    ON Remove.storeId = Actual.storeId
                    AND Remove.productType = Actual.productType
                    AND Remove.occurredAt > Actual.occurredAt)
SELECT store.storeId, COALESCE(Regular.newPrice, 0) as regularPrice,
                      COALESCE(Diesel.newPrice, 0) as dieselPrice
FROM Store
LEFT JOIN Latest_Change as Regular
ON Regular.storeId = Store.storeId
AND Regular.productType = 1
LEFT JOIN Latest_Change as Diesel
ON Diesel.storeId = Store.storeId
AND Diesel.productType = 4
```

Some things to note -
I figured you weren't actually giving a product a price of 0.  This means that you're not looking for the individual call that went out, with both prices listed - you're going for the last change that happened, for each product.  Which is why I pivoted/unpivoted that table like I did.
Needless to say, this statement reports the last entered change that was 'confirmed'.  This is *not* the last confirmation of a change (indicated by `dadthr`), however.

Comment: I didn't choose structure of these files. I can't change as400 version. This solution is almost perfect for me because I just want to extract store who is managed with us dialer. Comma and distinct was misspelled. How if i want to output the last regular and last diesel into this sql? `Latest_Change` output last regular or last diesel price only.

Comment: #corrected errors, thanks# - Yes, `Latest_Change` outputs only the last regular/diesel per-row (however, there was an error which caused it to ignore product type in the comparison, now fixed).  Which is why I have the final `SELECT` outside of that, `LEFT JOIN`ing twice to that table (once per regular, once per diesel).  That was the only way to get the last of _each_ of those columns for a given store, which may **not** be on the same row.

Comment: `Latest_Change` is not correct again. For example, store 502 is their 51 times with always 1.394 as regular price with all possible value of diesel.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not able to reproduce your problem.  Did you copy the statement again after I modified it?  I initially left off an important part of the `EXCEPTION JOIN` criteria.  If so, perhaps you could provide some additional source data, so I know what to look for.

Comment: I just recopied it and it's the same result

Comment: I don't know why, but the request is more fast with `SELECT *` than `SELECT storeId, productType, newPrice`. (3 times faster with star over 100 request -> `Total : 3.83 sec` with star and `Total : 9.56 sec` with all columns)

Comment: I edited your Sql. This work now and this do want i wanted with very decent times. I went from 6 sec to 1 sec. I have learned alot with your sql, thanks alot!

Comment: The speed increase is bizarre, but probably related to how it's optimizing the query.  I'd see if it's recommending any indicies, and look into whether or not those help.  If you could post what you did to my query to solve your problem, I'd appreciate it, if only so I know what I missed about your situation (either as an additional answer, or an edit to mine).

Comment: I already edited your answer. **`Thanks for your edit!`**
`This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.`

Comment: WITH Store (storeId) as ( SELECT DISTINCT cia#st FROM Wbdcia00), 
Price_Change (callGroup, occurredAt, productType, newPrice) as (
SELECT cie#en, ciedhc, 6, cie$or
FROM Wbdcie00 WHERE cie$or > 0 UNION ALL SELECT cie#en, ciedhc, 3, cie$di FROM Wbdcie00 WHERE cie$di > 0), 
Confirmed_Changes (STOREID, OCCURREDAT, PRODUCTTYPE, PRICE) as (
SELECT WarehouseCall.cia#st, Change.occurredAt, Change.productType, Change.newPrice FROM Wbdcia00 as WarehouseCall JOIN Wbdapp00 as Call ON Call.danoid = WarehouseCall.cia#ap AND Call.dastat IN (1, 4) JOIN Price_Change as Change ON Change.callGroup = da#env)

Comment: SELECT * FROM Confirmed_Changes as a WHERE a.OCCURREDAT = (SELECT MAX(b.OCCURREDAT) FROM Confirmed_Changes as b WHERE b.STOREID = a.STOREID AND b.PRODUCTTYPE = a.PRODUCTTYPE)

Comment: Err, yeah, I'd seen the revisions.  Except 1) In a worse-case situation, that `WHERE` clause _may_ be executed per-row.  2) Your results are not pivoted into the format you specified.  3) There's no difference in the results that _are_ gathered between the two versions - they're semantically identitcal.

Comment: 1) In us case, we remove at least 50% of rows in `Confirmed_Changes`. So in the worst case, the `WHERE` may be executed maximum 200 times. Maybe 350 times in 10 years. 2) That's correct for me like that. 3) Between which version? Mine and your? Or my attempts of modification?

Comment: 1) You didn't remove _any_ rows in `Confirmed_Changes` - all that happened to that CTE is you renamed the columns.  You eliminated `Latest_Change` which did 'remove' rows - except that you're still getting the same effect because of that last `WHERE` clause (net zero change).  You also doubled(ish) your final result count because you didn't correlate price change rows for warehouses. 2) Shoulda changed the desired format, then.  3)  Your modifications do not generate any significant differences (exclusion of non-changed stores aside).

Comment: 1) With `Call.dastat IN (1, 4)`. I got 50% less rows. I should correlate price change rows? Faster? 2) I'll edit 3) Your sql was not working as expected initially